# Уникальный индекс по полю из другой таблицы

Tags: sql, база-данных, mariadb

Возможно глупый вопрос, но можно ли добавить уникальный индекс для таблицы order_component по `(order_component.order_id,component.component_type_id)` ? Мне нужно чтобы в заказ нельзя было положить 2 предмета из одной категории, поэтому нужно добавить уникальный индекс по типу компонента.

[image: Схема]

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Даже теоретически.

Comment: *Мне нужно чтобы в заказ нельзя было положить 2 предмета из одной категории* Тогда схема не соответствует предметной области.

Comment: Можно попробовать сделать проверку на программном уровне, но это лишняя нагрузка на программу(но все же как одно из решений пойдёт)

Comment: @Akina как тогда лучше спроектировать, не хочется пихать все категории как столбцы в одной таблице